# Error after implementing new @autoreleasepool code

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, automatic-ref-counting

I'm changing my iPhone app to implement the ARC and leave old memory management behind.

I'm trying to implement the "main.m" code as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([flipAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

The problem is that "flipAppDelegate" was a .mm file and now when I try to compile my cpp code the "unknow type name 'class'" error shows up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you `#import "flipAppDelegate.h"` anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

How about it?

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"flipAppDelegate");
```